# custom AngularJS directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am making a custom directive in AngularJS 1.4.3. Below is my directive code.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('psFramework').directive('psFramework', function () {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        scope: {

        },
        controller: 'psFrameworkController',
        templatesUrl: 'ext-modules/psFramework/psFrameworkTemplate.html'
    }
});
```

Here is my controller `psFrameworkController`

```
'use strict';

angular.module('psFramework').controller('psFrameworkController',
    ['$scope',
        function ($scope) {

        }
    ]);
```

My module `psFrameworkModule`

```
'use strict';

angular.module('psFramework', ['psMenu', 'psDashboard']);
```

And templates `psFrameworkTemplate.html`, which is very simple

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

When I put `<ps-framework></ps-framework>` tags in my `index.html` file then it somehow does not render the template.

Here is my `index.html`

```
<body class="container-fluid">
    <ps-framework></ps-framework>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `templateUrl` NOT `templatesUrl` and I like to suggest to add the `restrict` property too:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('psFramework').directive('psFramework', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {

        },
        controller: 'psFrameworkController',
        templateUrl: 'ext-modules/psFramework/psFrameworkTemplate.html'
    }
});
```